# How to create multiple pdf for multiple plot in R?

Tags: r, pdf, plot

For each seed, I have two plots. For three seeds, all the six plots are saved into one pdf. But I want them in separate pdf for each seed. For example, for the first seed, I want two pdf, one for `sample[,1]` and another for `sample[,2]`. And the same for the rest of the seeds.

```
pdf(file = "example plots.pdf")
library(LearnBayes)
seeds <- c(314159,523626,626789)
for (seed in seeds) {
  set.seed(seed)
  x <- c(11, 5, 2, -5, 7, 2, -11, 9, -5, -5, -4, 17, 2, -10, -11, -10,
         -4, 2, 1, 13)
  a <- 0.1
  b <- 0.1
  c <- 0
  d <- 100^2
  M <- 1e3
  sample <- array(NA, dim=c(M,2))
  mu <- mean(x)
  sig2 <- var(x)
  for( m in 1:M ){
    mu <- rnorm(1, (length(x) + 1/d)^(-1) * (sum(x) + c/d),
                sqrt( sig2/(length(x) + 1/d) ))
    sig2 <- rigamma(1, .5*length(x)+a+.5,
                    .5*sum( (x-mu)^2 ) + 1/(2*d)*(mu-c)^2 + b )
    sample[m,] <- c(mu,sig2)
  }

  par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  plot( density( sample[,1] ), main=paste("plot_1 for seed", seed))
  plot( density( sample[,2] ), main = paste("plot_2 for seed", seed))
  setwd("C:/Users/mnudd/Desktop/StackExchange")
  save(sample,file =paste0("hrs_sample_4Q_", seed, ".RData"))

}
dev.off()
```

Comment: You could move `pdf` and `dev.off` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: I am getting only one pdf for the first seed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code with some modifications (marked with comments) that will save the plots as you want them. The problem with the previous code is that your were overwriting your pdf plot, as it was called only once as `pdf(file = "example plots.pdf")`. I modified the code so you save 3 pdf plots with different names.

```
#Moved wd outside the loop
setwd("C:/Users/mnudd/Desktop/StackExchange")
for (seed in seeds) {
  set.seed(seed)
  x <- c(11, 5, 2, -5, 7, 2, -11, 9, -5, -5, -4, 17, 2, -10, -11, -10,
         -4, 2, 1, 13)
  a <- 0.1
  b <- 0.1
  c <- 0
  d <- 100^2
  M <- 1e3
  sample <- array(NA, dim=c(M,2))
  mu <- mean(x)
  sig2 <- var(x)
  for( m in 1:M ){
    mu <- rnorm(1, (length(x) + 1/d)^(-1) * (sum(x) + c/d),
                sqrt( sig2/(length(x) + 1/d) ))
    sig2 <- rigamma(1, .5*length(x)+a+.5,
                    .5*sum( (x-mu)^2 ) + 1/(2*d)*(mu-c)^2 + b )
    sample[m,] <- c(mu,sig2)
  }

  par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  #Moved pdf inside the loop and modified the name of the saved file
  pdf(file = paste0("example_plots_", seed,".pdf"))
  plot( density( sample[,1] ), main=paste("plot_1 for seed", seed))
  plot( density( sample[,2] ), main = paste("plot_2 for seed", seed))
  #Moved dev.off inside the loop
  dev.off()

  save(sample,file =paste0("hrs_sample_4Q_", seed, ".RData"))

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you could wrap the routine into a function and run a `sapply` loop.

```
seeds <- c(314159, 523626, 626789)

FUN <- function(x) {
  pdf(paste0("file", x, ".pdf"))  # initialize .pdf device
  set.seed(x)  # use seed from `sapply` loop
  # do stuff and plot.............................
  samp <- replicate(2, rnorm(1e3), simplify=FALSE)
  op <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
  lapply(samp, plot)
  par(op)
  # ..............................................
  dev.off()  # close .pdf device
  }
sapply(seeds, FUN)
```

*Note:* PDFs will be saved into your `getwd()` unless you specify a location `pdf(paste0("<LOCATION>/file", x, ".pdf"))`.